# Opencv SVR auto_train error "Assertion failed (sv_count != 0) in do_train"

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I am using OpenCv SVM for regression and it worked fine,
 when I tune the parameters manually. 
But when I use the grid search method to optimize the parameters:

```
1.It kept giving me the "Assertion failed (sv_count != 0) in do_train" error
```

when I used it on 
a large data set (about 10000 instances and 10 features).

```
2. I got good results when I tried the same code
```

with a smaller data set (100 instances and 5 features).

Could someone please help me figure out what the problem could be?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post your method/other code?

Comment: I have the exact same problem (1.). Have you found the solution yet?

Comment: Not really. I used cross-validation to get the optimum parameters.