# OpenCV: SVM train_auto assertion sv_count != 0 failed

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm

This is basically a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873124/opencv-svr-auto-train-error-assertion-failed-sv-count-0-in-do-train), but I'm asking it anyway, because the original poster either solved the problem or lost interest.

I want to auto train a regression SVM with OpenCV using the following code:

```
CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type = CvSVM::EPS_SVR;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF;
params.term_crit = TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, (int)1e7, 1e-6);

CvSVM svm;
svm.train_auto(_data, _resp, _var_idx, _train_idx, params);
```

Here _data and _resp are Mats holding the feature vectors and responses, _var_idx containing the active features and _train_idx the active samples. For the parameter grids the default values are used. Unfortunately, the code produces the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (sv_count != 0) in do_train, file /home/.../opencv-2.4.9/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp, line 1346

When I run a single regression with parameters selected by hand it works fine. And when I switch to a classification problem (and change the corresponding parameters and SVM type) it also works. In that case for single training as well as for auto training.

Can somebody point out what the problem is?

**EDIT:**

The code as it is above also leads to another error:

> OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (The parameter p must be positive) in CvSVM::set_params

And for the CvSVM::NU_SVR this would be the same with parameter nu. The Problem goes away when I set these parameters, but I don't understand why this error occurs in the first place. When I look at the documentation of train_auto it says that p (and nu) are evaluated using their corresponding default grids. So why do I have to set them?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 2:**

I've made a small example that suffers from this problem. Just in case anyone want to try it out and reproduce the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml/ml.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    Mat X(1000, 2, CV_32FC1);
    Mat Y(1000, 1, CV_32FC1);

    randu(X, -2, 2);

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        Y.at<float>(i,0) = pow(X.at<float>(i,0),2) + pow(X.at<float>(i,1),2) - 1;
    }

    CvSVMParams params;
    params.svm_type = CvSVM::EPS_SVR;
    params.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF;
    params.term_crit = TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, (int)1e7, 1e-6);
    params.p = 0.1;

    CvSVM svm;
    svm.train_auto(X, Y, Mat::ones(1,2, CV_8U), Mat::ones(1,1000, CV_8U), params);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does svm_type=CvSVM::NU_SVR work? For single regression, do you mean one-class SVM?

Comment: @greeness Yes, NU_SVR is working. No, with "single regression" I mean one regression on the same data with a fixed parameter set.

Comment: Have you tried `train_auto(X, Y, Mat(), Mat(), params);`?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should assign initial values to these parameters.

```
param.C = 1;  //initialize parameter
param.p = 5e-3;  //initialize parameter  
param.gamma = 0.01;  //initialize parameter
```